# Object Is Not JSON Serializable When Using JSON Dumps

Tags: python, json, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am using an async method to return an array of objects and I am getting a "TypeError:  is not JSON serializable" error and I am not sure how to correct it. Here is my code:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return await response.text

class NewStoriesHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    async def get(self):
        self.set_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response = requests.get(
        "https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/newstories.json?print=pretty")
        data = response.json()
        story_list = []
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
           for url in data:
               story_list.append(fetch(session, url))

        print(story_list)
        self.write(json.dumps(story_list, default=json_util.default))
        self.finish()
```

I tried to return Json back to the method but it was unsuccessful and I not sure what it is expecting back. The loop return an object for each call and appends it to the array.

Comment: Please provide output of line `print(story_list)`

Comment: Means what it says -- if an object contains things Python doesn't know how to translate into JSON, you get that error. We can't know how to fix it unless you tell us what `fetch(session, url)` returns.

Comment: It returns an array of objects

Comment: What *specific* kind of object? Some objects are serializable, others aren't.

Comment: @Jack please edit your question and add example, how does it look.

Comment: You're running `print(story_list)`, but you aren't showing us what that `print()` outputs. That's very pertinent information.

Comment: There is no output from the print, it just hits the exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it looks to me like you are adding co-routine objects to the list, rather than the results of the coroutines.

i think you should `await` each fetch before adding them to the list. I haven’t been able to run the code because i’m currently traveling, but you probably also need a strategy to start each task’s execution before you await it.